# Partial match when using vlookup formula

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to fill an empty column of a sheet with data from another sheet. For this I'm depending on `VLOOKUP`

Here is my formula

```
=VLOOKUP(RC[-6],Sheet2!C[-3]:C[-2],2,FALSE)
```

I'm looking for a name in a sheet and takes value from that row. But the issue I'm facing is sometime the value in sheet2 (Where I have to do `vlookup`) which is actually a person's name doesnt have middle name. It only have first and last name. Since the lookup value as middle name, in that situation the lookup doesn't yields any result. So the plan is to do lookup with the first and lastname only even there is middle name in the lookup value. How can we accomplish that

For example our lookup value (`RC[-6]`) could be `Donald John Trump`. But in search sheet (Sheet2) the name could be only `Donald Trump`. So in result I need `Donald Trump` row, but it's not since we have `Donald John Trump` as lookup value.

Comment: Performing a `If` like "if vlookup(with middle name) = no result then vlookup(w/o middle name" could work.

Comment: But the lookup value is just from a single cell. Its not in different cells of the row. So the look up value could be like Donald John Trump. But in the search sheet only Donald Trump available.

Comment: Do you have sample data? Also re-tagged it. You don't need VBA solution do you?

Comment: you can [use wildcards in vlookup](http://www.excelvlookuphelp.com/tutorial-vlookup-and-the-wildcard-characters-and-for-partial-matches/) like searching for `FirstName * LastName` Therfore you would need to replace eg the space in `Donald Trump` by `" * "` note the spaces before and after the asterisk (replace only if there is only one space, if there are 2 spaces then there is already a middle name).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ But since lookup value from a single cell how can we distinguish firstname or lastname from it.

Comment: use find function to find the space: Eg this formula `=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))=1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1) & " * " & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),A1)` makes `Donald Trump` into `Donald * Trump` but doesn't change `Donald John Trump` So this could be used as search value.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Why did you post this as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 yes you are right, that's no hint anymore, I worked it out as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use wildcards in VLOOKUP](http://www.excelvlookuphelp.com/tutorial-vlookup-and-the-wildcard-characters-and-for-partial-matches/) like the asterisk `*` for any amount of characters or the `?` for one character.

- So if your search term is `Donald Trump` but you want to find also `Donald John Trump` then you need to add an asterisk `Donald *Trump`:

  ```
  =IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))=1,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1) & " *" & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),A1)
  ```
- Or if your search term is `Donald John Trump` but you want to find also `Donald Trump` then you need to substitute the middle name with an asterisk `Donald *Trump`:

  ```
  =IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))=2,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1) & " *" & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)),A1)
  ```

You can then use the above formula as first argument in your VLOOKUP, or use a helper column so you can see what the actual search term is.